# Will mysql_secure_install script block master updates to slave?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5

I had setup two virtual mysql database servers in two oracle linux 6 vm's, which come with mysql server ver 5.1.47

Master named prod_master & slave named prod_slave1.

I installed both the mysql servers in two virtual hosts machines with mysql_secure_installation script :

1. which removes test db
2. change root password
3. disable remote login

The bound ip-address for prod_master to 192.168.1.100 & prod_slave1 to 192.168.1.101

- I had enabled the bin-log and index in my.cnf on master and relay log in slave. On master, I had created user repl_user and granted replication privileges and started master. The master has successfully started and created bin-log.
- When i issued the commands show master status, show binary logs, the logs are visible.
- Coming to the slave, after configuring the my.cnf, issued the change master to using repl_user with credentials and issued the command start slave.
- slave started. Then issued the command show slave status : it shows slave status like "connecting to master" in the slave attribute connection i/o error : unable to connect to the master with port no 3306.

I had granted the replication privileges with @192.168.1.%, and also issued the port on slave side. Now, here the major issue is: I couldn't connect remotely to the master or even from slave. From master connecting to slave :

```
mysql master> mysql -h 192.168.1.101 -uroot -proot ( not able to connect )
```

I am not even getting connection refused error. And the same case even from slave to the master. After starting the slave i had viewed the slave mysql.log found that slave replication thread getting dead. due to connectivity issue. Is it problem , that i had installed using the script mysql_secure_install. Please guide me. I Want to know whether :

1. grant issue for replication problem (or)
2. because of the script mysql_secure_install

Note : Both the master and slave vm-machines are pinging on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

If by `disable remote login` you mean it added `skip-networking`, you'll want to remove that from your my.cnf and restart mysql

Comment: @ kormoc, thatz not the issue, RHEL 6 comes with SE Linux which need to be in permissive mode, existing IP tables need to be flushed, if you dont have any rules exist so far. This worked out for me.